# Can't parse xml from curl response

Tags: php, xml, curl

I use the code below to get xml data from some API:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"><file><auth>myapikey</auth><warenhouse/></file>';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://somesite.com/xml.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I get xml data successfully something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<responseCode>200</responseCode>
<result>
<whs>
<warenhouse>
<city>New York City</city>
<address>Some Address</address>
<number>1</number>
<phone>1111111</phone>
</warenhouse>
<warenhouse>
...
</warenhouse>
</whs>
</result>
</response>
</xml>
```

but I can't parse and echo only cities using

```
$parser = simplexml_load_string($response);
foreach($parser->warenhouse as $item) {
 echo $item->city;
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is a bit malformed , remove that `</xml>` from the end.

You need to loop like this

```
foreach ($xml->result->whs->warenhouse as $child)
{
        echo $child->city;

}
```

#### The code..

```
<?php
$xml= <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response>
<responseCode>200</responseCode>
<result>
<whs>
<warenhouse>
<city>New York City</city>
<address>Some Address</address>
<number>1</number>
<phone>1111111</phone>
</warenhouse>
<warenhouse>
</warenhouse>
</whs>
</result>
</response>
XML;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($xml->result->whs->warenhouse as $child)
{
        echo $child->city;

}
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
New York City
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/134009)

Comment: Are you generating the XML or you getting it from an API ?